# Chrome extension is not loaded by Selenium in Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to load a chrome extension named scrapbook using Java. I searched a lot and tried different proposed methods to do so. However, none of those are working. Even it does not load the window maximized, let alone loading the extension. Here is the code:

```
package automationFramework;
import java.io.File;
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class FirstTestCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\SOFTWARE\\CHROME EXTENSIONS\\chromedriver_228.exe");
        String pathToExtension = "C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Google\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1\\oegnpmiddfljlloiklpkeelagaeejfai\\0.26.3_0\\";
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("-load-extension=" + pathToExtension);
        options.addArguments("-open-maximized");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you adding extension by giving the extension folder as input?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, then I used the `.crx` file to add it on launch. I'm using python, but in Java it would be the same by using:

```
options.add_extension("idmgcext.crx");
```

the `.crx` file is in the same folder as the script or provide full path if in another folder you can get [chrome extension](https://chrome-extension-downloader.com/) for `.crx` file.